# rewrite if else null check using optionals

Tags: java-8, option-type

Is there a way to rewrite this using Optional and lambdas in a more succinct and clear way?

```
private boolean pricingIndicator(AvgBuySellPriceTerm avgBuySellPriceTerm){
    if(avgBuySellPriceTerm == null){
        return false;
    }else{
        if(avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator()!= null && ! avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator().isEmpty()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not answering to your question but just putting it up in a more streamlined way:both `else` statements are unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion with `Optional`:

```
private boolean pricingIndicator(AvgBuySellPriceTerm avgBuySellPriceTerm){
    return Optional.ofNullable(avgBuySellPriceTerm)
                   .map(AvgBuySellPriceTerm::getIndicator)
                   .map(i -> !i.isEmpty()) // return true if getIndicator
                                           // is not empty
                   .orElse(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it, using an `Optional::ofNullable` and the classic `map`, `filter` and `isPresent` methods

```
private boolean pricingIndicator(AvgBuySellPriceTerm avgBuySellPriceTerm){
    return Optional.ofNullable(avgBuySellPriceTerm)
                   .map(AvgBuySellPriceTerm::getIndicator)
                   .filter(ind -> !ind.isEmpty())
                   .isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!Optional.ofNullable(t)
         .map(AvgBuySellPriceTerm::getIndicator)
         .map(List::isEmpty)
         .orElse(true);
```

Not sure this is more readable though.

Comment: This doesn't return true when required. In fact, it doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: Indicator can be a string

Comment: Of course, that’s far away from being more readable. The reader needs to interpret the code with its negations, to find out, what it actually does. On the other hand, it’s consistent or even taking the OP’s desire to the max, to replace what can be expressed as a simple `return avgBuySellPriceTerm != null && avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator()!= null && !avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator().isEmpty();` with code doing fancy `Optional` stuff…

Answer (score 0):

Again, not using lambdas here but keeping it readable. The first `if` statement can be omitted, so it can all boil down to:

```
private boolean pricingIndicator(AvgBuySellPriceTerm avgBuySellPriceTerm){
    if(avgBuySellPriceTerm != null && avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator()!= null && !avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator().isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: But you removed the null check of `avgBuySellPriceTerm`.

Comment: This will break if `avgBuySellPriceTerm` be null.

Comment: Yeah sorry, fixed

Comment: (copy and paste drama)

Comment: “The first `if` statement can be omitted” is not quiet correct, as you already had to find out, but can be merged with the subsequent condition, as you did with the edit. So this sentence need to get adapted too. Then, consider that statements of the form `if(condition) return true; [else] return false;` can be replaced by a simple `return condition;`, i.e. `return avgBuySellPriceTerm != null && avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator()!= null && !avgBuySellPriceTerm.getIndicator().isEmpty();`

Comment: @Holger you're right, that was just bad phrasing on my side, English not being my first language. I meant It all could be merged in just one if condition. Good suggestion about the second part too, thanks.